# Not Able to access updated state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to access my updated state in a function. Here is my scenario:

I have a **getImages()** function which gets called when either the component loads for the first time or the user reaches to the end of the page while scrolling to fetch new images via API call.
On first time component load, I want to give the random page value that's why I am passing a random number from first useEffect hook and when user reaches to the end of page, I want to make use of pageNum state. But every time while reaching to the end of page, the pageNum value is coming as 0 in the API call as well as in the console log. I was expecting the updated pageNum state as everytime in the end of getImages() function, pageNum state is getting incremented by 1. I checked react dev tools and there the pageNum state is updating correctly.

[image]

Here is the snippet of my code:

The images state is updating correct, it is making use of existing state and appending new images on every call.

```
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        getImages(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) === document.body.scrollHeight){
                getImages();
            }
        });
        
    }, []);

    async function getImages(pageNo){
        let response;
        console.log(pageNum);
        if(pageNo === undefined){
            response = await fetch(`<API URL>&page=${pageNum}`);
        }
        else{
            response = await fetch(`<API URL>&page=${pageNo}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();

        setImages(function(currentState){
            return [...currentState, ...data];
        });
        setPageNum(function(currentState){
            return currentState + 1;
        });
    }
```

Please let me know if I am missing out anything.

Answer (score 1):

### Reason:

The problem happened bc you not put pageNum as useEffect dependencies. because you add event listener at when component mount for first time ( pageNum is 0 that time). And because you not adding pageNum to useEffect dependencies pageNum value will never update.

### Solution:

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        getImages(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchImgOnCrollHandler = () => {
            if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) === document.body.scrollHeight){
                getImages();
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("scroll", fetchImgOnScrollHandler);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', fetImgOnScrollHandler);
        }
    }, [pageNum]);

    async function getImages(pageNo){
        let response;
        console.log(pageNum);
        if(pageNo === undefined){
            response = await fetch(`<API URL>&page=${pageNum}`);
        }
        else{
            response = await fetch(`<API URL>&page=${pageNo}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();

        setImages(function(currentState){
            return [...currentState, ...data];
        });
        setPageNum(function(currentState){
            return currentState + 1;
        });
    }
```

Now **everytime** pageNum update. scroll event attached to window will be removed and add new one with new pageNum to it

Comment: Thanks Takashi for your quick response. I am just wondering that then why images were updating correcting. For images also, the initial value was an empty array so for every image fetch request, all the images should have been just appended to an empty array and the number of images should have been remain constant, isn't it?

Comment: Attach scroll event on Component did mount is enough. Why do we need to attach each time when `pageNum` changes?

Comment: But i think it will fetch many times.

Comment: It shouldn't as you removing the listener. I don't like this behaviour, but at time you creating a function for the listener, you using the state at that time, so you have to update it your self. This is quirk of React <-> browser API, tho?

Comment: Many times I used as a quick fix `setTimeout` wrapper which is not working in this your case. But it may help. Just do not use it too often :)

Comment: @VMT it will fetch everytime pageNum change, and it's behavior we want.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @mchowdam state in react is differrent from variable. if you dont remove it and attach it again. value of state in handle function of event inside useEffect **will not** change. This is common issue when ppl start using React.

Comment: @NikhilBansal you update images by passing a callback to setState function. you  **did NOT** used state there. that callback function will be passed the true value of current state. that's why your image update correctly.
Btw. Is my answer correct?

Comment: @VMT I think that is the answer.

Comment: @NikhilBansal check [this](https://youtu.be/4UZrsTqkcW4?t=16331) please

Comment: @TakashiAnji today I tried to pass the dependency as pageNum as told and it worked for me. Also, just for reference here, found that on every event listener getting attach it attaches the callback function with the values present at that time, and that was the reason pageNum was always 0 inside getImages() function although state was correctly getting updated. And now since we are removing and attaching the listener again on pageNum update, it makes sure to use the updated pageNum value inside the event callback function. Thanks everyone for the help.